# CORS implementation with Spring 3.x

Tags: java, spring, cors

I want to know what are the possible solutions for allowing Cross Origin Resource Sharing between my Website and API Server. And what will be the best approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the possible solutions:

1) Implement as it is implemented in Spring 4.2 using CORS Filter (Link for JIRA of this Feature https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9278 and the implementation is here https://bitbucket.org/thetransactioncompany/cors-filter/src/cba65d9a30e1db457df57d7689dee3244026a916/src/main/java/com/thetransactioncompany/cors/?at=master)

2) By using Interceptor

3) Simply write a filter that adds cross origin headers in all servlet responses

4) Using JSONP as your data type in ajax request

I will prefer the first one.

Comment: Can you provided some reference what should be its actual implementation?

Comment: Here is the Jira for this Feature
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9278
and you can find its implementatio here: https://bitbucket.org/thetransactioncompany/cors-filter/src/cba65d9a30e1db457df57d7689dee3244026a916/src/main/java/com/thetransactioncompany/cors/?at=master

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)